# SVG not displayed in webkit based browsers

Tags: svg

I have encountered some strange behavior with SVG images in webkit based browsers. They are shown in Firefox and Chrome Canary but in Chrome 28.0.1500.71 and Safari 6.0.5 a transparent SVG image is shown instead (or the image is not correctly loaded). When I right-click the SVG image URL in the inspector and open it in a new tab, though, the image is displayed correctly.

Here is my sass:
`[role="banner"] {
background: image-url("svg/header.svg") 15px top no-repeat;
    }`

The paths are correct and also the CSS. I double-checked it. Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: It looks like the problem is photoshop. My graphic designer gave me a photoshop file from which I exported the header as a png into Illustrator and converted it to a SVG.

Comment: Please add your SVG source code or link to your page.

Comment: I removed the code from my site, exchanging the SVG images with png images. The display problem seems to really result from the fact that my SVG images where png files exported from PS and imported into Illustrator, from where I exported them as SVG files. I tested with SVG files that were originally created in Illustrator and therefore pure vector graphics. These SVG files (created from 'real' vector graphics) were then displayed in the browsers.